# two kinds of passive voice

Tags: sentence-construction, passive-voice

*You have been sent this message because you signed up to receive a weekly newsletter.*

*This message has been sent to you because you signed up to receive a weekly newsletter.*

I assume that the above sentences have the same meaning. Are they really interchangeable? Is not there after all some stylistic or semantic difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct, the two phrases have identical meaning and can be used interchangeably. The only very minor difference I could think of is that the first version sounds more personal, while the second sounds more professional. The first sentence focuses more on "you," the recipient, while the second version focuses on the message. The difference, however, is so small that it does not matter.

Comment: Genreally true, but: the subject rarely if ever takes the emphasis in a sentence. It's put at the beginning for this reason! :-)

Answer (score 1):

By rules, some verbs have 2 objects, a person and an object. Either can be used as a subject of the passive sentence (as in your example).

A person is usually used because a person is usually more important than an object. However, it really depends on  where you want to put emphasis on.

So generally speaking both is correct.

PS. In your case the 2nd sentence sounds better as in this case the message is more important than the receiver.